# When not to use RxJava's Observable?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-android

For example, I have a simple Manager in my application where I trying to keep everything `reactive`:

```
class AppLockManager {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

    private val rxHelper: RxHelper
    private val securityManager: DiarySecurityManager

    private var locked = false
    private var lastUnlockTime: LocalDateTime? = null

    constructor(rxHelper: RxHelper, securityManager: DiarySecurityManager) {
        this.rxHelper = rxHelper
        this.securityManager = securityManager
    }

    fun shouldLock(): Observable<Boolean> {
        return securityManager.isSecutiryEnabled()
                .doOnNext { logger.debug("isSecurityEnabled: $it") }
                .map { it && !locked && isLockTimerExpired() }
                .doOnNext { logger.debug("shouldLock: $it") }
                .compose(rxHelper.applySchedulers())
    }

    private fun isLockTimerExpired(): Boolean {
        if(lastUnlockTime == null) return true
        val timerExpiredMoment = lastUnlockTime!!.plusSeconds(30)
        val now = LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(timerExpiredMoment)
        val isExpired = LocalDateTime.now().isAfter(timerExpiredMoment)
        logger.debug("timerExpiredMoment: $timerExpiredMoment / now: $now; isExpired: $isExpired")
        return isExpired
    }

    fun setLocked(): Observable<Void> {
        return Observable.create<Void> {
            this.locked = true
            it.onCompleted()
        }.compose(rxHelper.applySchedulers())
    }

    fun setUnlocked(): Observable<Void> {
        return Observable.create<Void> {
            this.locked = false
            lastUnlockTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        }.compose(rxHelper.applySchedulers())
    }

    fun resetLockTimer(): Observable<Void> {
        return Observable.create<Void> {
            lastUnlockTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        }.compose(rxHelper.applySchedulers())
    }

}
```

It's a simple class that count time and emits `true` from `shouldLock()` when my application must be locked.

There is how I use it:

```
fun lockAppIfNeeded() {
    appLockManager.shouldLock()
            .doOnNext { logger.debug("shouldLock: $it") }
            .flatMap { if(it == true) Observable.just(it) else Observable.never() } // flow down only if it == true
            .flatMap { appLockManager.setLocked() } // then lock
            .subscribe(sub({}, Throwable::printStackTrace, { // use onComplete as source Observable is empty
                securityManager.anyPassword().subscribe {
                    if (it) {
                        view.navigateToAskPassword() // anyPassword is true
                    } else {
                        view.navigateToFirstPasswordSetup() // anyPassword is false
                    }
                }
            }))
}
```

Looks ugly, isn't it? :)

I just can't find right operator to combine empty Observable(`appLockManager.setLocked()`) with `securityManager.anyPassword()` wwitch return Observable that emits one item.

This has led me to believe that I should not use RxJava for methods like `appLockManager.setLocked()`.

**Should I use Observables here?** Specially for `setLocked()`/`setUnlocked()`/`resetLockTimer()` methods which just updating `AppLockManager` and returns no data at all.

Answer (score 2):

Using nested subscription is bad code smell. To use another `Observable` after the completion of another, you can `concat` Observables.

You code can be simplier. For example, instead of using this :

```
.flatMap { if(it == true) Observable.just(it) else Observable.never() }
```

you can use `filter`instead.

So removing nested subscription + `filter` will lead to this code :

```
fun lockAppIfNeeded() {
    appLockManager.shouldLock()
                 .doOnNext { logger.debug("shouldLock: $it") }
                 .filter { it } // flow down only if it == true
                 .flatMap { appLockManager.setLocked() } // then lock
                 .ignoreElements() // throw away appLockManager items
                 .concatWith(securityManager.anyPassword())
                 .subscribe {
                       if (it) {
                            view.navigateToAskPassword() // anyPassword is true
                       } else {
                           view.navigateToFirstPasswordSetup() // anyPassword is false
                       }
                })
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's a good solution. But I just google a little bit and found info about `Completable`. It became `@Beta` in last `RxJava` update and it fits my needs.

Comment: `filter { it }` does not replace `.flatMap { if(it == true) Observable.just(it) else Observable.never() }` as in flatMap I return `Observable.never()` which will never call `onComplete`.

Comment: Check that your app don't leak memory with never. (I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to presented by @dwursteisen will be to use `Completable`. According to [changelog](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/blob/1.x/CHANGES.md) it just became `@Beta`.

There is improved `lockAppIfNeeded()` method:

```
fun lockAppIfNeeded() {
    appLockManager.shouldLock()
            .doOnNext { logger.debug("shouldLock: $it") }
            .filter { it } // flow down only if it == true
            .toCompletable()
            .concatWith(appLockManager.setLocked()) // then lock
            .andThen(securityManager.anyPassword())
            .subscribe(sub {
                if (it) {
                    view.navigateToAskPassword() // anyPassword is true
                } else {
                    view.navigateToFirstPasswordSetup() // anyPassword is false
                }
            })
}
```

Where `setLock()` returns `Completable`:

```
fun setLocked(): Completable {
    return Completable.fromAction { this.locked = true }
            .compose(rxHelper.applySchedulersToCompletable())
}
```

Also, `Observable` in `shoudlLock()` can be replaced with `Single` (`Observable` that emits one item).